# powershell com internetexplorer catch popup window

Tags: parsing, internet-explorer, powershell, popupwindow, com-object

I'm trying to use powershell to automate and parse a website.
Everything works great until I "click" on a link and it opens in a new window.
How can I access that window so I can parse it?

```
$ie = New-Object -com Internetexplorer.application 
$ie.Visible= $true
$ie.Navigate("http:/.....")
....
# find a link... 
$link.click(); # a new popup window open up.
# how can I get access to the new popup window?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`NewWindow3` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768337(v=vs.85).aspx) so that you can grab the object when it gets created.

```
Raised when a new window is to be created. Extends NewWindow2 with additional information about the new window.
Syntax
        Private Sub object_NewWindow3( _
    ByRef ppDisp As Object, _
    ByRef Cancel As Boolean, _
    ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
    ByVal bstrUrlContext As String, _
    ByVal bstrUrl As String)
```

Comment: I am not sure how either, but you could try `$ie.NewWindow3 = { param(...) # rest of function definition }`. Based on the documentation it looks like it might be the way.